# WebsocketRails Authentication with tiddle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, token, jwt

I'm developing an Ionic project which uses a Rails API.
To authentication i'm using the gem [TIDDLE](https://github.com/adamniedzielski/tiddle) and my Ionic application pass X-USER-EMAIL and X-USER-TOKEN into Request Readers.
How to proceed with [WebsocketRails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) with this authentication strategy?